# change title‘s background and font color for FloatingActionsMenu

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to change title’s background and font color ，how can do it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added only this line

> label.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

```
private void createLabels() {
    Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), mLabelsStyle);

    for (int i = 0; i < mButtonsCount; i++) {
      FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton) getChildAt(i);
      String title = button.getTitle();

      if (button == mAddButton || title == null ||
          button.getTag(R.id.fab_label) != null) continue;

      TextView label = new TextView(context);
      label.setTextAppearance(getContext(), mLabelsStyle);
      label.setText(button.getTitle());
      label.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);      
      addView(label);

      button.setTag(R.id.fab_label, label);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem, but i try and it work fine :D
In your XML file , you use :

```
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Instead :

```
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

And setColor , setTitle like the sample.